# Move file in Ubuntu 14.04 LST Desptop

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, lenovo

I'm wanting to move a folder from downloads to a directory in the "usr/share/"here some where". I've tried manually, but permission denied. Is there a way to do it manually? I can try CLI if you guys tech a command line.

Thanks,

Pipa.

Comment: Better explain why you want to move something to `/usr/share`. It's not usually recommended especially if you're new to Linux.

Comment: you need to be ROOT to modify the contents of that directory. Mohit's answer below is correct

Answer (score 1):

**1.Using file manager**
 open Nautilus as root `kgsudo nautilus` then u can copy file from `~/Downloads` to `/usr/share`.

**2.Using command line**

1. Open terminal.

   2. `cd ~/Downloads`
   3. `sudo mv file-name /usr/share`